# Could dropping a laptop lower its performance?

Tags: laptop, cpu, gpu, lenovo-laptop

It still works normally and testing it with games, it seems to work as well as it did before it fell, userbenchmark yields good results too, but can the CPU or the GPU or the RAM be slightly damaged ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no real way to know.

Electronics tend to fall into the "either work or don't" category, not "slow or fast" - but physical components such as fans & hard drives can have far more subtle damage,
A drop will lead to one of three potential outcomes.

1. Something broke; it doesn't work.
   Time for a repair shop.
2. Something broke but doesn't yet show symptoms.
   Wait & see…
3. Everything survived.

Short of stripping the entire machine & testing every component, only option 1 is certain. 2 & 3 need time &/or hope. Whether you can trust it for a day, a month or a year is entirely guesswork.

The only sensible course of action if no damage is apparent is to make sure your backup strategy is solid.
It could fail at any time… or not.

Comment: +1 for mentioning backups ...